# Block indentation - python

Tags: python-3.x

New coder here. I arrived at a problem with the indentation/block of a snippet of code. I am wondering if someone can help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

symbol = ''
url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + symbol + "&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&start=0&count=100&output=atom"
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
html = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
entries = html.findAll("entry")

shouldContinue = True
link = ""
for entry in entries:

    if shouldContinue and (
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-k" or entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-q" or
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "20-f"):


        firstUrl = entry.find("link")["href"]

        uClientFirstUrl = uReq(firstUrl)
        page_html_firstUrl = uClientFirstUrl.read()
        uClientFirstUrl.close()
        htmlFirstUrl = soup(page_html_firstUrl, 'html.parser')

        tds = htmlFirstUrl.findAll("table")[1].findAll("td")
        foundtd = False
        for td in tds:
            if foundtd == True:
                link = "https://www.sec.gov" + td.find("a")["href"]
                foundtd = False
            if "xbrl instance" in td.text.lower():
                foundtd = True

            shouldContinue = False

return link

    def getCash(url, symbol):
        uClient = uReq(url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()

        xml = soup(page_html, 'xml')

        cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue")
        if len(cash) == 0:
            cash = xml.findAll("ifrs-full:Cash")
            if len(cash) == 0:
                cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents")
                if len(cash) == 0:
                    cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:Cash")

        return cash;
```

I am getting an error at line 42 "def getCash(url, symbol):". I do not know which blocks I have to indent to which one.

Comment: You have to "un"-indent the entire `def getCash` method. If you are not using an IDE it probably makes sense to use one for formatting errors like that.

Comment: So from lines 42 down to 57 (return cash;), I have to un-indent all those,  bringing them to the left margin?

And I am using PyCharm as my IDE

Comment: Honestly the error is clear: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`. BTW `return link` is invalid: `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: "An error" ... Why not include it? Adding the traceback helps us help you.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that the `getCash` method in indented (which matters in python). You only need to move it back. There also seems to be a rogue `return link` statement in your code which i have removed in the example below (I am assuming it is a pasting error).

```py
for entry in entries:

    if shouldContinue and (
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-k" or entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-q" or
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "20-f"):


        firstUrl = entry.find("link")["href"]

        uClientFirstUrl = uReq(firstUrl)
        page_html_firstUrl = uClientFirstUrl.read()
        uClientFirstUrl.close()
        htmlFirstUrl = soup(page_html_firstUrl, 'html.parser')

        tds = htmlFirstUrl.findAll("table")[1].findAll("td")
        foundtd = False
        for td in tds:
            if foundtd == True:
                link = "https://www.sec.gov" + td.find("a")["href"]
                foundtd = False
            if "xbrl instance" in td.text.lower():
                foundtd = True

            shouldContinue = False


def getCash(url, symbol):
    uClient = uReq(url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    xml = soup(page_html, 'xml')

    cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue")
    if len(cash) == 0:
        cash = xml.findAll("ifrs-full:Cash")
        if len(cash) == 0:
            cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents")
            if len(cash) == 0:
                cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:Cash")

    return cash
```

Comment: Ok cool, there is no error showing up in my IDE. Thank you buddy

Comment: if that worked for you, can you accept the answer as a solution? Thanks

Comment: Okay, now that there is no error showing up, the code finishes with the message "Process finished with exit code 0". How do I get this code to print the results in my IDE? Or ultimately into excel with an openpyxl or xlwings module.

Comment: That's ultimately a separate question; to print a variable use `print()` eg. `print(cash)` . process finished with exit code 0, means that the code has stopped running, but it run without issues. To write into Excel, you should probably read the documentation of the libraries, attempt a solution and then raise a separate question on stack overflow if necessary.

Comment: I added print(cash) after the return cash function in my code and it does not print anything. It still finises with a process finished.

Comment: are you calling the method anywhere? it doesn't look like it's called in the example above, and without looking at the full code it's impossible to tell what's happening, but again this is a separate question.